# geom_ribbon multiple start stop timepoints

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot `geom_ribbon` based on whether data is within `yes` or `no`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(date = 
                   as.Date(c("01/01/1998", "10/01/1998", "15/01/1998", 
                             "25/01/1998", "01/02/1998", "12/02/1998", "20/02/1998"), "%d/%m/%Y"),
                 counts = c(12, 10, 2, 24, 15, 1, 14),
                 yes_no = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no"))
df
#         date counts yes_no
# 1 1998-01-01     12    yes
# 2 1998-01-10     10    yes
# 3 1998-01-15      2     no
# 4 1998-01-25     24    yes
# 5 1998-02-01     15    yes
# 6 1998-02-12      1     no
# 7 1998-02-20     14     no

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = counts)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = counts, fill = yes_no), color = NA, alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

which gives the wrong plot with the ribbons overlapping.

Essentially, I want to create the `geom_ribbon` equivalent of this `geom_rect` version:

```
#use start and end dates:
df2 <- data.frame(start = 
                    as.Date(c("01/01/1998", "15/01/1998", 
                              "25/01/1998", "12/02/1998"), "%d/%m/%Y"),
                  yes_no = c("yes",  "no", "yes", "no"),
                  end = as.Date(c("15/01/1998", "25/01/1998", "12/02/1998",
                                  "20/02/1998"), "%d/%m/%Y"))
df2
#        start yes_no        end
# 1 1998-01-01    yes 1998-01-15
# 2 1998-01-15     no 1998-01-25
# 3 1998-01-25    yes 1998-02-12
# 4 1998-02-12     no 1998-02-20

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = counts)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(data = df2,
            aes(xmin = start, 
                xmax = end, 
                fill = yes_no,
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf), 
            inherit.aes = FALSE,
            alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

This is good but rather than the rectangle version, I want `geom_ribbon`. Seems a basic question but cant figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using run-length encoding of your `yes_no` variable. Example below.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(date = 
                   as.Date(c("01/01/1998", "10/01/1998", "15/01/1998", 
                             "25/01/1998", "01/02/1998", "12/02/1998", "20/02/1998"), "%d/%m/%Y"),
                 counts = c(12, 10, 2, 24, 15, 1, 14),
                 yes_no = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no"))

# Run-length encoding (rle)
rle <- rle(df$yes_no)

# Determine starts and ends of rle
starts <- {ends <- cumsum(rle$lengths)} - rle$lengths + 1

# Create indices of groups from starts/ends. 
# Ends is offset by 1 so it includes the start of the next run.
groups <- mapply(seq, from = starts, to = ends + 1, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# Re-index the data.frame
df2 <- df[unlist(groups),]
# Take yes_no from rle
df2$yes_no <- rep(rle$values, lengths(groups))
# Assign groups
df2$groups <- rep(seq_along(groups), lengths(groups))
# Delete last row because we've offsetted 'ends' by 1, the last will be NA
df2 <- head(df2, -1)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = date, y = counts, group = groups)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = counts, fill = yes_no), color = NA, alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: ... I feel this might be a good use case for `ggh4x::stat_rle()`... :D

Comment: Yeah I thought so too but it doesn't work well with dates :( https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4155

Comment: The essence is exactly the same, so well spotted!

Comment: I'm just a big fan of this package :D

Comment: @teunbrand Could `ggh4x::stat_difference` be hacked to use here too (difference between `x = 0` line and the line itself)? I feel there is a cleaner `ggh4x` solution since you provided this great answer!