# Background bars in ggplot2 using geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I have daily flow data in a dataset I've called "dat1_na".

It spans between ~1940 and ~2020 so there's 18,780 lines in this dataset.

str(dat1_na) is:

```
'data.frame':   18780 obs. of  9 variables:
 ...
 $ MLd    : num  96 34 34 20 34 34 52 34 34 26 ...
 $ Date   : Date, format: "1943-09-19" "1943-09-07" "1943-09-08" "1943-09-11" ...
 ...
 $ Climate: chr  "Dry" "Dry" "Dry" "Dry" ...
```

So it's a simple Line graph (hydrograph) showing MLd (the daily flow rate) against time which is no problem.
However, I'm trying to shade the background using geom_rect according to the 'Climate' part of the dataset which only has 2 possible values: "Dry" and "Wet". The issue is that I can't get the background to show up properly. I know the data is being read right because if I tweak my code a bit I can see the dry years and wet years where they should be:

```
ggplot(dat1_na, aes(x=Date, y=MLd, xmin=Date, xmax=Date, ymin=0, ymax=6000)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#231EDC") + 
  geom_rect(aes(colour=Climate), alpha=0.2) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[graph using aes(colour=Climate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJRjf.png)

What I really want is it to be transparent and sit behind the line graph. I can't seem to get it working though. I've tried a few versions of code including things in the ggplot() statement, or the aes() statement, but nothing really works. I have code which I think should work, but nothing from the geom_rect shows up (except in the legend which looks correct).

```
ggplot(dat1_na, aes(x=Date, y=MLd, xmin=Date, xmax=Date, ymin=0, ymax=6000)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#231EDC") + 
  geom_rect(aes(fill=Climate), linetype=0, alpha=0.2) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[graph using aes(fill=Climate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLMGQ.png)

I'm wondering if its to do with the number of rows in my data (~18,000) causing the geom_rect to be just too small and for only the outline being large enough to show up.  The trouble with that is I can't get the outline to be transparent. I assume the code is drawing a rectangle for each row, either pink or green depending on the value of dat1_na$Climate.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data to reproduce your issue. If you want to post your data use `dput()`.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first 20 rows of data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334121/geom-ribbon-multiple-start-stop-timepoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to demonstrate without a reproducible example, so let's create one with the same column names and types as your own data:

```r
set.seed(8)

dat1_na <- data.frame(MLd = 40 + cumsum(sample(seq(-5, 5), 100, TRUE)),
                      Date = sort(as.Date(sample(seq(-9601, 9601), 100, TRUE),
                                          origin = '1970-01-01')),
                      Climate = c('Dry', 'Wet')[round(1.5 + 
                                  cumsum(runif(100, -0.01, 0.01)))])
dat1_na
```

The key here is to create an little data frame for the rectangles, based on the start and end dates of changes in `Climate`

```r
library(tidyverse)

rect_frame <- dat1_na %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(change = lag(Climate) != Climate, 
         change = c(TRUE, change[-c(1, nrow(.))], TRUE)) %>%
  filter(change) %>%
  mutate(End_Date = lead(Date))
```

Now, when we plot, ensure that we draw the `rect` layer first. It should be filled by the `fill` aesthetic rather than the `color` aesthetic, and the layer needs to be passed `rect_frame` as its `data` argument:

```r
ggplot(dat1_na, aes(x = Date, y = MLd)) + 
  geom_rect(data = rect_frame, 
            aes(fill = Climate, xmin = Date, xmax = End_Date, 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(colour = "#231EDC") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. OK that solution and the one danlooo linked to both created a new data frame with start and end dates for each climate status and then drew the geom_rect using that new dataframe rather than the hydrograph's dataframe. I think this confirms my suspicion that my code was trying to draw ~18000 little rectangles (which is why only the outline was showing up).